# Having problem in react native back handler function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using back handler function of react native and I hacve just declared it on login screen to disable the back button to navigate back to my splash screen. But It is calling in all my other screens. Like the main screen and others but I have only declared it in my login component. Pls help me out to solve this issue. thanks

Login screen:

```
    backAction = () => {
    return true;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.backAction,
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your listener is enabled since login screen, therefore all your other screens are performing as requested.

You are on the right track, near to correct.
Replace the following code at `componentWillUnmount`:

```
BackHandler.removeEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.backAction
    );
```

Replace `componentWillMount` with

```
BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.backAction
    );
```

Comment: No It is still calling in other screens :( any other sol?

Comment: did u mean to remove or add the above code in componentWillUnmount?

Comment: not working this too. but I have solved the issue somehow

Comment: Please explain how did you fix it, I am also facing the same one..